# Removing Specific Text from a String in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I want to delete part of string label1 which is in a gallery and recover the result in the same label without having to create a new label to see the result
I found that the "Substitute" function is only usable with the use of the Set function; Set(myVar;Substitute(Label25.Text; "a"; "b") and that forces me to retrieve the result in another label which takes as text "myVar" different from the initial (label1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the result of the Substitute function in a variable - you can use it directly in the label within the gallery. For example, if the existing Text property in your label is set to

```
ThisItem.Value
```

You can update it to use the Substitute function, and you will have the result in that label directly:

```
Substitute(ThisItem.Value; "a"; "b")
```

Comment: I want to use the substitute function in the "OnUncheck" property of a Checkbox and
when I uncheck checkbox1 the Checkbox1.Text  have to be removed from "ThisItem.address"

Comment: Power Apps' language is a declarative one, so you would typically write the label's Text expression to something similar to `If(Checkbox1.Value; Substitute(ThisItem.address; Checkbox1.Text; ""); ThisItem.address)`. Any time the checkbox is checked (or unchecked), the formula will be recalculated and the value will be updated.